# Compiling and rendering handlebars template with vanilla JS

Tags: javascript, templates, handlebars.js

I am writing an application that uses handlebars.js but [The example code on their website](http://handlebarsjs.com/) uses JQuery so as do many other online resources. However, I want to simply compile and render a handlebars template using vanilla js.

This is the HTML template

```
<script id="entry-template" type="text/x-handlebars-template">
  <div class="entry">
    <h1>{{title}}</h1>
    <div class="body">
     {{body}}
    </div>
  </div>
</script>
```

The JS I have for the compilation is below, as suggested in the answer to a similar question here 
[Does Handlebars require jQuery](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30950150/does-handlebars-require-jquery/30950240#30950240)

```
var source = document.getElementById('entry-template').innerHTML;
var template = Handlebars.compile(source);
```

Assume my JSON is stored in a variable called myData.

When it comes to rendering the template with JQuery you can simply do

```
$('#data-section').append(template(myData));
```

But I want to use vanilla JS so I'm doing this:

```
var compiledHTML = template(myData);    
var dataContainer = document.getElementById('data-section');
dataContainer.appendChild(compiledHTML);
```

but I get the error

```
Uncaught TypeError: Failed to execute 'appendChild' on 'Node': parameter 1 is not of type 'Node'.
```

How do I get this to work?

Answer (score 3):

You can use the `Element.insertAdjacentHTML` method which is cross browser friendly.
See docs here:
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/insertAdjacentHTML

There are four options for how to insert the compiled template into the DOM:

1. beforebegin (before opening tag or as a previous sibling)
2. afterbegin (first child)
3. beforeend (last child)
4. afterend (after closing tag or next sibling)

In my case I was attaching a template to the end of the body tag so it looked like so
`document.getElementsByTagName('body')[0].insertAdjacentHTML("beforeend", myHbsTemplate(VM));`

Comment: Thanks Andre. insertAdjacentHTML is definitely very useful. The issue I was having was due to me confusing Element objects with nodes i.e. https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/API/Node & https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element

Comment: Thanks for the answer, works for me! For the future reference: use "document.body" instead of "document.getElementsByTagName('body')[0]".

Answer (score 2):

The output of calling a compiled template is a string, and not a DOM tree. You might want to use `innerHTML` instead.

```
dataContainer.innerHTML = compiledHTML;
```

Comment: That works perfectly. Does this work because there is some type conversion occurring behind the scenes?

Comment: @rjbultitude somewhat like that https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/innerHTML

Answer (score 0):

The issue seems to be with the fact that the variable *compiledHTML* is a string. The solution I have gone with is to use DOMparser, which allows me to convert the sting to a DOM node that I can then pass into appendChild.

The code I'm using is this

```
var parser = new DOMParser();
var convertedHtml = parser.parseFromString(compiledHTML, 'text/xml');
dataContainer.appendChild(convertedHtml.documentElement);
```

I had to use *documentElement* because the HTML which results from the parse generates a *HierarchyRequestError* error.